# MS Access Exports Records to Excel in Wrong Order

Tags: excel, ms-access

When we export a report to Excel format the records are in a different order than when the report is displayed in Access and when the report is exported to a PDF file.

The records are in the correct order when displayed in the Access report and in the exported PDF file.

The report is 100 pages in length. The number of records in the Excel file is 1950.

I'm wondering if the large number of pages or records is causing Access to change the order of the records.

Any debugging suggestions?

We're using Access 2007.

Ed

Comment: How are you outputting the records, DoCmd.OutputTo?  There was a comment (unresolved) on how someone else was having this issue as well. I think it is unrelated to the set size. If order is paramount, a workaround would be to read the data into a recordset and write it out to Excel line by line, then format the workbook programatically.  Or, there is a CopyFromRecordset method in Excel which can extract the contents of a recordset to the specified sheet.

Comment: Do you have an `Order By` clause on your query?

Comment: Order is never guaranteed without an Order By